# Skip decoding Unicode string while unmarshalling: golang

Tags: go, unicode

I have this JSON:

```
{
    "code":"\u5728\u4e30\u5fb7\u5c14Berro\u8212\u9002\u76841\u623f\u5355\u4f4d"
}
```

And this struct

```
type Text struct {
    Code string
}
```

If I use any of the `json.Unmarshal` or `NewDecoder.Decode`, the Unicode is converted to the actual Chinese. So `Text.Code` is

`在丰德尔Berro舒适的1房单位`

I don't want it to convert, I want the same unicode string.

Comment: Do you also need to have the unicode characters escaped when they are not escaped in the JSON file? Eg. what if the JSON file looks like this: `{"code":"在丰德尔Berro舒适的1房单位"}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with custom decoder https://play.golang.org/p/H-gagzJGPI

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type RawUnicodeString string

func (this *RawUnicodeString) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    *this = RawUnicodeString(b)
    return nil
}

func (this RawUnicodeString) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(this), nil
}

type Message struct {
    Code RawUnicodeString
}

func main() {
    var r Message
    data := `{"code":"\u5728\u4e30\u5fb7\u5c14Berro\u8212\u9002\u76841\u623f\u5355\u4f4d"}`
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &r)
    fmt.Println(r.Code)
    out, _ := json.Marshal(r)
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, we have some services in PHP which want to use the same data, I already implemented the custom MarshalJSON which works for me. Thanks.

Comment: Just found a small problem in this, it is adding double quotes `" "`  to the string. When you print `r.Code` you can see the string with `" "`. I tried to trim the first and last byte of the array inside `UnmarshalJSON` and it worked. But I am not sure if that is the correct solution.

Comment: @RanveerSingh you can try to use un unmarshaller `RawUnicodeString(b[1:len(b)-1])` Should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `json.RawMessage` instead of string. https://play.golang.org/p/YcY2KrkaIb

```
    package main

    import (
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
    )

    type Text struct {
        Code json.RawMessage
    }

    func main() {
        data := []byte(`{"code":"\u5728\u4e30\u5fb7\u5c14Berro\u8212\u9002\u76841\u623f\u5355\u4f4d"}`)
        var message Text
        json.Unmarshal(data, &message)
        fmt.Println(string(message.Code))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to escape your backslash by preceding it with another backslash.

```
func main() {
    var jsonRawOriginal json.RawMessage = []byte(`"\u5728\u4e30\u5fb7\u5c14Berro\u8212\u9002\u76841\u623f\u5355\u4f4d"`)
    var jsonRawEscaped json.RawMessage = []byte(strings.Replace(string(jsonRawOriginal), `\u`, `\\u`, -1))

    fmt.Println(string(jsonRawOriginal)) // "\u5728\u4e30\u5fb7\u5c14Berro\u8212\u9002\u76841\u623f\u5355\u4f4d"
    fmt.Println(string(jsonRawEscaped))  // "\\u5728\\u4e30\\u5fb7\\u5c14Berro\\u8212\\u9002\\u76841\\u623f\\u5355\\u4f4d"

    var a interface{}
    var b interface{}

    json.Unmarshal(jsonRawOriginal, &a)
    json.Unmarshal(jsonRawEscaped, &b)

    fmt.Println(a) // 在丰德尔Berro舒适的1房单位
    fmt.Println(b) // \u5728\u4e30\u5fb7\u5c14Berro\u8212\u9002\u76841\u623f\u5355\u4f4d
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Ok9IVJnxp-8